# Best time to ask if a search was good/bad

Tags: search-results, faceted-search, voting

We have a internal document system where call center people search in real time while on calls for some specific files, or more accurately some information in the files. After the user clicks to the document to get the info they searched for we are wondering what might be the best way to ask if the file was helpful or not. Just a simple thumbs up or thumbs down. Wondering if there is a best practice to elicit this feedback while in the flow.

Comment: Are you in a place where you could shadow the users of the call center system and watch them interact with the documents and their customers at the same time? If the feedback button is always visible, it might get ignored, but if it appears at the wrong time, it can be annoying (or also get ignored). Watching the interaction flow to see the "found it" moment could be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I sense it would have to be designed in a way it does not get in the way of the user task. A simple thumbs up/thumbs down option beside the result makes a lot of sense.

Of course, I wonder what the user need for this is? "As a user I can rate search results so that the search engine returns better results".

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation. And yes that would be along the lines of the user story. Our issue at the moment is we have been using clicks on results as an affirmative to the result but when we watched users using the system we noticed they click in to a result detail page and then back out result list to look for another result to click on. This behavior then invalidated what we had been looking at which was boosting results that are clicked on.

Comment: I'm sure Google will have a way of determining what search algorithms are better than others

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a compact banner having

`"Search results for <query+xyz> enter preformatted text here"
<small section with Upvote/Downvote the results icon>`

Things I would take care of :

- User should not be forced to do the voting.
- The voting part should not be blocking user-flow in any way.

In addition, you can keep a track of whether user clicks on top few search results, if he/she does then most probably you have delivered the right results.